# CDA FHIR mapping

Tags: hl7, hl7-fhir, cda, hl7-cda

I am trying to add support for [sidecar applications](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/smart-on-fhir/LxzSzSSdtf8/sD7rkuZMX0sJ) in EHR platforms. I am taking a pure implementer's approach to build an intermediate representation (such as an XML) for mapping CDA<--->FHIR. I am using the smart-on-fhir as the reference implementation for this. The CDA I am trying to use is the Australian extension - ereferral (www.digitalhealth.gov.au/implementation-resources/clinical-documents/EP-0936-2012/NEHTA-0967-2012).

Is it possible to create such an intermediate representation using the smart-on-fhir (or any other FHIR) reference implementation? Has anyone else tried this?

While searching for actual implementations I came across these repos:

- [github.com/jmandel/sample_ccdas](http://github.com/jmandel/sample_ccdas)
- [github.com/amida-tech/fhir2ccda](http://github.com/amida-tech/fhir2ccda)
- [github.com/amida-tech/cda-fhir](http://github.com/amida-tech/cda-fhir)

The FHIR group has some hand crafted [examples](https://github.com/FHIR/cda-examples-to-fhir). Are there any equivalent CDA examples for these FHIR resources?

I have read couple of web articles and white paper documents regarding the challenges between the transforms, such as:

- David Hay's [blog](https://fhirblog.com/2013/12/13/fhir-meet-cda/) says "*FHIR document is that it is like an object graph, rooted in the composition resource*", so is their an equivalent representation for CDA?
- Rene Spronk's [article](http://www.ringholm.com/docs/04200_en.htm) about whether HL7 v3 is a message or a document. What are the implications for an implementer who has to handle and validate representations across both CDA and FHIR
- [Lantana Group position paper](https://www.lantanagroup.com/wp-content/uploads/CDA-on-FHIR-Position-Paper_April-10-2015-Update1.pdf) - "*If or when FHIR can accommodate the full CDA use case, the future holds the promise of seamless integration and information sharing between clinical documents and APIs*". Does this mean that CDA<--->FHIR transform is not possible at this stage of the FHIR standard?

Apologies for cross posting it in both SO and FHIR community forums: http://community.fhir.org/t/cda-fhir-mapping-implementations/211/1

Answer (score 3):

CDA to FHIR is fairly straightforward and it looks like you've already found some repositories that do that.

FHIR to CDA is also fairly straightforward - assuming all you care about is something that is valid. You may need to adjust those libraries for use in the AU/NZ locales.

That said - [Keith Boone](http://motorcycleguy.blogspot.se/2015/09/cda-fhir-working-backwards-to-go.html) has some blog posts about some of the challenges in mapping between the two, as there will always be quirks.

The biggest hurdle you will have is loss of fidelity. A CDA (at least a C-CDA here in the states) comes with so much HL7v3 cruft that by turning it into FHIR, you're instantly not going to be able to re-create the original C-CDA from FHIR. The CCD template has evolved so much that you find documents that contain C32 elements, C-CDA 1.1 templateIds, and maybe someday C-CDA 2.1 templateIds. So while you can reasonably make a valid C-CDA out a FHIR bundle, you will have to pick a specific implementation and version to target.

My startup https://www.redoxengine.com has a JSON version of CDA that yo can see on the docs page. It's designed for simplicity, but can be mapped back and forth to FHIR resources.